# use the software gisto to save my code not share is free?

Tags: gist

I just use the software Gisto to write my code and save them (not open), it seemed like a part of github and what you wrote on gisto will also keep in gist. But I heard that github just free for open source project, since as a beginner for me, I just use gisto like a useful notebook, I'm not sure it will charge or not? Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not Github customer support](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: Sorry for I didn't know that, I just guess people may meet the same experience and solved, I'll be careful hereafter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gisto co-creator here. To answer some questions and provide some clarity:

- Gisto is a free and open source software project
- Gisto is NOT part of GitHub (and not associated with GitHub in any way), it is independent project using GitHub gist service as a medium via GitHub API.
- Gisto is free to use and no charging will take place
- Regarding the privacy concerns please advise the link kindly provided by @HaWe above https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/#secret-gists
- If you have more questions, see Gisto FAQ page http://www.gistoapp.com/faq/ or just contact us

Comment: Thanks for your useful clarity. however, I still wonder                                                                                 1. the storage limit of gisto for the all code file, since I always worried how many files and their version can I use 2. if I choose not share when I create gist on gisto, could people see this gist from github or by a certain URL (or it still based on my github settings )?

Answer (score 0):

Gisto saves the snippets as public/secret gists. You need a payed subscribtion only for private repositories, public and secret gists can be created with a free subscription.

But secret gists are not private like mentioned here: https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/#secret-gists

Comment: Thank you! But for me, I have been using gisto a long time, I use them as privacy type, and they keep my code, every vision, not charge me, I feel very confused about that...